# IS condition not working in AS3 (extra site wont let me post)

Tags: if-statement, actionscript-3

I have a pretty straight forward if statement

```
var mynum:Number = 0; 
var myclip:MovieClip = new thisclass();
addChild(myclip);
```

in the class file

```
var i:int = 0;
for (i; i<stage.numChildren; ++i)
{
  if (stage.getChildAt(i) is thisclass)
  { trace("true"); }
}
```

and Im not getting the expected results?

Is there more to the "is" condition?

Comment: There are two possible issues. 1. Normally you don't work with the **stage** directly. Unless you explicitly state **stage**, you are not working with it. For example, if you write scripts on the main timeline, you are in the **root**, rather than on the **stage**. 2. If you address **stage** or **root** in the class constructor, you will get errors, because constructor is executed exactly after the **new** statement and before the next line after **new**. Thus, in the class constructor you have no access to the **stage** or **root**. You should listen for the ADDED_TO_STAGE event first.

Comment: @Organis by the look of this code it's written in the timeline. So yes, the hierarchy should be stage -> root -> MC.

Answer (score -1):

Solved the issue by using parent instead of stage, not sure why it didn't like stage

Comment: Because your stage isn't a direct parent of your thisclass. `getChildAt()` does not traverse the entire display tree, it only traverses the current node of that tree. You called it from `stage` meaning you want root node, okay, but your instance isn't a direct parent of root. You should check `myclip.parent` to find out what you should list to find it.